# Limiting Summary field and Grouped Sum fields by date range

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a crystal report where the view I created pulls records and the report grouping is done on this criteria...CDate ({lg_hl_domnioCosts;1.DATE_ORDERED}) = Aged0To30Days. This works fine for the group but I have some fields that sum certain columns in the report but they take all of the records into account. How can I make those columns sum only by the date range above as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a Running Total in crystal reports.
You can find this below Formula fields in "Field Explorer".

This way you can get the sum of fields you have on the report.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the grouping on `CDate ({lg_hl_domnioCosts;1.DATE_ORDERED}) = Aged0To30Days` use the formula in `Record selection` so that only criteria you are looking will be picked and there will be no issue with the summary calcualtion.